# how to attach a 3D map to a 2D map using gmapping and octomap

Tags: navigation, octomap, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have used amcl to build a 2D map and rgbdslam+octomap to build a 3D map. These two maps are for the same room. Now I want to attach the 3D map onto the 2D map, like the picture below, is there a way of doing this? I tried change the parameters in .yaml file but it does not work.Thanks for any suggestions !!!

[image description http://mobilemanipulationchallenge.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/arm_mover_joint_goal.png](http://mobilemanipulationchallenge.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/arm_mover_joint_goal.png)

by the way, the image is from [here](http://mobilemanipulationchallenge.org/?page_id=117)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43486/how-to-attach-a-3d-map-to-a-2d-map-using-gmapping-and-octomap/) by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-09-09**:
You built a 2D map with AMCL? Do you mean you built it with gmapping?

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-09-09**:
opps sorry. yes I built the map using gmapping but i use amcl to do the localization on this 2D map. i mixed these two, my bad

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-07-02**:
did you solve the problem? it would be greate if you could tell us your result, because I am having the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know the octomap can produce a 2d map from itself by projecting it. This would then also fit.

Nevertheless, you should be able to use both independently by just suppling the 2d map via the map server as normal. If they are build together/based on the same data, they should then also match each other.

If they are build using different localization data, you'll need to align them. I don't know anything automatic, so the easiest might be to modify the 2d map origin.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-09-10**:
I got the 2D map from laser scan and 3D map from RGBDSlam + Octomap,but for the same room, does it count as "based on the same data"? And I tried modifying the 2D origin in .yaml file but it cannot solve the problem that the 3D map is tilted comparing to the 2D map. Any ideas?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-11**:
If they don't fit together easily, then you have a problem. Is using the 2D map generated by the octomap an option?

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-09-12**:
yes but the one using laser scan is much more clear and has less noise. is there a way to change the orientation of a 2d map in rviz?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-12**:
No, rviz only displays. To change the 2D map, you can do two things: 1. Change the origin in the yaml, 2. Just edit/rotate the image - essentially the map is just an image.